# codeigniter/php error undefine property in private function

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I test `new self()`, `$this` both work fine but I want to know:

> What difference between them will it cause a problem to me later when
>   using in difference situation?

Sencond how to get variable in private function `load_user_record($rows)`

> I got error **undefine property** please help

```
private function load_user_record($rows)
{
    $this->user_id = $rows->id;
    $this->hashedPassword = $rows->user_pwd;
}

private function find_user_record($user_name)
{
    $this->db->where('user_name',$user_name);

    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_user');

    $result = $query->result();

    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        foreach($result as $rows):
```

/************************* what difference ******************************/

```
        /*
         *  $item = new self();
         *  $item->load_user_record($rows);
         *  $user_result[] = $item;
         */
            $this->load_user_record($rows);

            $user_result[] = $this;
```

/************************* End HERE ******************************/

```
        endforeach;

        return $user_result;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

public function check_user_exist($user_name, $password)
{
    $find_user = $this->find_user_record($user_name);

    if($find_user !== FALSE)
    {
```

/********************* HERE error undefine property*********************/

```
            foreach($find_user as $user):

            /* $user_id = $user->user_id;
             * $hashed_password = $user->hashed_password;
             * using this 2 variable above work
             */

               $this->load_user_record($user);
            // using this load_user_record not work

            endforeach;
```

/************************* End HERE ******************************/

```
        if( password_verify( $password, $hashedPassword )) {
            if (password_needs_rehash($hashedPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)) {
                $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $newHashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                $this->db->where('id',$user_id)
                         ->set(array(
                            'user_pwd' => $newHashedPassword,
                            'last_login' => $time
                         ));
                if(!$this->db->update('tbl_user'))
                    return FALSE;
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Error happen

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Login::$id
>
> Filename: core/Model.php
>
> Line Number: 77
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_Project\application\models\backend\Login_model.php
>   Line: 10 Function: __get
>
> File:
>   C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_Project\application\models\backend\Login_model.php
>   Line: 49 Function: load_user_record
>
> File:
>   C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_Project\application\controllers\backend\Login.php
>   Line: 27 Function: check_user_exist
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_Project\index.php Line: 316 Function:
>   require_once

---

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Login::$user_pwd
>
> Filename: core/Model.php
>
> Line Number: 77
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_Project\application\models\backend\Login_model.php
>   Line: 11 Function: __get
>
> File:
>   C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_Project\application\models\backend\Login_model.php
>   Line: 49 Function: load_user_record
>
> File:
>   C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_Project\application\controllers\backend\Login.php
>   Line: 27 Function: check_user_exist
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_Project\index.php Line: 316 Function:
>   require_once

---

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: hashedPassword
>
> Filename: backend/Login_model.php
>
> Line Number: 53
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_Project\application\models\backend\Login_model.php
>   Line: 53 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_Project\application\controllers\backend\Login.php
>   Line: 27 Function: check_user_exist
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_Project\index.php Line: 316 Function:
>   require_once

and is my code right in OOP? Don't mind me if I'm wrong in OOP it my 1st code in OOP.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you used the same variable `$find_user`. Change the code to:

```
foreach($find_user as $user):

        $this->load_user_record($user);

endforeach;
```

Comment: i have change to this but still same error     foreach($find_user as $user):
    
 $this->load_user_record($user);
     
endforeach;